# MYSQL: How to update multiple columns with same value

Tags: mysql

I have an update query that calculates a `TIMEDIFF` on a large number of `DATETIME` records:

`UPDATE eventlog SET downtime = TIMEDIFF(up_stamp,down_stamp);`

This works, but I need to set this `TIMEDIFF` value to another column as well as `downtime`. Something like this (doesn't work):

`UPDATE eventlog SET downtime, downtime_adj = TIMEDIFF(up_stamp,down_stamp);`

I know I can combine them like this:

`UPDATE eventlog SET downtime = TIMEDIFF(up_stamp,down_stamp), downtime_adj = TIMEDIFF(up_stamp,down_stamp);`

But this will recalculate the same time diff 2x as many times as needed. What's the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that it is possible to use a **user-defined variable**, so that `TIMEDIFF()` needn't be run twice.

Try this:

```
UPDATE eventlog SET downtime = @x := TIMEDIFF(up_stamp,down_stamp), downtime_adj = @x;
```

Here is the documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html

**Disclaimer:**

I just happened to read up after seeing your question. I am not proficient in SQL.

Hope that helps `:-)`

Comment: Does this solution prevent the possible left-right evaluation issue @a1ex07 warned of? I found another example: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=52861 .

Comment: From the docs: "As a general rule, other than in SET statements, _you should never assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same statement._" And also, "For other statements, such as SELECT, you might get the results you expect, _but this is not guaranteed._"

Comment: That being said, _this particular statement_ seems to evaluate from left-to-right in `Maria-DB 5.5.36`. For example, something like `UPDATE eventlog SET downtime = @x, downtime_adj = @x := TIMEDIFF(up_stamp,down_stamp)` resulted in `NULL` values for the `downtime` column. I would say there is no way around undefined behavior (that I know of). The best bet is to test it on your database.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this and it seems to work on my mysql :

```
UPDATE eventlog SET downtime = TIMEDIFF(up_stamp,down_stamp), downtime_adj = downtime;
```

`downtime` will be set with the timediff and `downtime_adj` will use the new `downtime` as it's value.

Comment: Docs says "Single-table UPDATE assignments are generally evaluated from left to right. " (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html). Personally I wouldn't take chances and assume that "generally" means "always"...